# yii regular expression validation

Tags: javascript, php, regex, validation, yii

I'm use pattern matching validation in YII1.
This is my code

```
array(
      'sd_fname','match',
      'pattern'=>'required a pattern',
      'message'=> 'Invalid Characters found'
),
```

I want a RegEx. that can recognize following tags
`<script src="any_url"></script>`
`<link src="any_url" rel="stylesheet"></link>`
The aim is to sanitize the input, to protect form XSS attack.
If there's another way for the same task, then please make me aware of that.

Comment: This question makes absolutely no sense, why would need a regex for script and link tags?

Comment: @ajmedway Sir! May be i ask question in an incorrect way...! I want to restrict the user to enter script and link tags in input field

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code for regex :

```
array(
      'sd_fname','match',
       'not' => true, 
      'pattern'=>'/<script.*>.*<\/script>/ims',
      'message'=> 'Invalid Characters found'
),
```

you can test regular expression: https://regex101.com/r/fE2bX5/1